# Unity3d: crossdomain.xml not being re-examined after a network failure

Tags: http, unity-game-engine, crossdomain.xml, unity-web-player

We have a game that communicates with a server (which has a proper crossdomain.xml file), and everything works fine using the web player.

But we are adding some logic to handle error conditions, and that is where we have run into a problem. What we want is for the user to do something in the game, and if there is a basic WWW problem (such as network or server being down), then the user gets a message with an option to "try again."

It seems as if WWW is caching the lack of crossdomain.xml file from the first call (when the server was down), and is not trying to find that file on the second call (when the server is back up).

Has anyone else encountered this, or have any other ideas about what's going on and how we might work around this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way to skip any cache would be to use a different server every connection - or at least make Unity think it's a different server.

Easiest way to achieve this is a [wildcard DNS record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record). This way if you fail connecting to `srv1.example.com`, try `srv2.example.com`, then `srv3.example.com` and so on.

If you have no access to wildcard DNS, you can always add a few subdomain records and switch between them.